# How to run a function on each file in a folder only once in Julia?

Tags: file, for-loop, julia

Sorry if this has been answered before but I am having some trouble finding a definitive solution to the following.  I have a folder where new files are added daily.  Everyday function, `fun1`, is looped through each file in the folder. What is the best way to ensure that function `fun1` runs on each file only once and does not run on the same file again the next day?

e.g. On day 1 `Folder` has one file: `file1`.  `fun1` then runs on `file1`.
On day 2 a new file, `file2`, is added to `Folder`. On day 2 `fun1` should run on `file2` but skip `file1`.

`fun1` does not actually modify `file1`, rather it uses the data from `file1` to modify an existing file, say `file1s`.

I thought about approaching this by moving the files that have had `fun1` run on them to a different folder with something like

```
for files = readdir(folder1, join=true)
    fun1(files)
    destination = replace.(file, "folder1"=> "folder2")
    mv.(file, destination)
end
```

But I don't know if this might introduce problems or complications or if this is frowned upon generally? I could also create a separate set of files that have been "processed" with something like

```
processed_files = DataFrame(filename=[])
all_files = readdir(folder1, join = true)
for file = setdiff( all_files, processed_files.filename)
    fun1(file)
    push!(processed_files.filename, file)
end
```

But I don't know if this would be efficient as overtime `processed_files` would grow very large.  I would really appreciate any comments on whether these are sound approaches or if there is a more idiomatic Julia way to achieve this? Thanks so much!

Comment: I am guessing that with this setup you also read and write the dataframe to disk daily to get the diff?

Comment: An alternative approach could be checking the date and time of creation of each file and comparing it with the date and time of the last time the script was run. Build systems like GNU Make come to mind

Comment: Extending @loonatick's idea, check the timestamp of `file1` compared to `file1s`, if it is newer or `file1s` is missing, then process `file1`.

Comment: awesome thanks so much guys! I didn't realize I could approach it like this.  As the `Folder` gets larger...say now we grow from `file1` to `file10^n`.  Does it still make sense to loop through each file checking time stamps or would it be preferable to just periodically convert `Folder` to a giant GDF, process each SubDataFrame and then move all processed files to a different folder?   I'm just at a loss as to which approach would be more efficient and reliable in the long run?

Comment: I could also rename the file after it is processed but would that be more reliable than actually moving the file to a different folder?  Sorry I don't really know what I'm doing so just wondering if keeping the folder the same in the directory somehow makes a difference in terms of making things less error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If keeping the Julia process alive is an option, one solution would be to monitor the folder for changes using the `FileWatcher.watch_folder()` function which is part of Julia's standard library.

The documentation can be found here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/FileWatching/

Here is an example:

```
julia> using FileWatching

julia> while true
         filename, event = watch_folder(".")
         @show filename event
       end
filename = "test1"
event = FileWatching.FileEvent(true, false, false)
filename = "test2"
event = FileWatching.FileEvent(true, false, false)
```

Notice the `while true` since once a change has occurred, `watch_folder` is non-blocking and returns the filename and event. In the example above, I created two files named `test1` and `test2` with `touch ...`, in the same folder where `julia` was started.

What's nice about this approach is that no constant polling is done but `watch_folder` uses the filesystem specific notification system to retrieve events. To my understanding, this is the cleanest solution to your problem.

Don't worry about files which have been added/modified while `watch_folder` was not "blocking", the changes are queued up, just like in a stream.

Comment: Thanks so much for this amazing answer!  Sorry I've been playing around with this and am still really confused about how to run a function on the new files coming in.  I am assuming I have to collect `filename` into an array with something like `push(newarray, filename)`, broadcast the function over `newarray` and then remove filename with something like `setdiff!(newarray, filename)` ?   But how can I perform these operations on `newarray` while it is constantly being modified by the while loop?  is this a case that would involve @async or Channel?

Comment: Sorry a bit slow on the uptake... I think I understand how to implement your solution now.  Would it be possible to use watch_folder on multiple folders simultaneously  without opening separate instances of Julia?

Comment: Glad you worked that out! Watching different folders could be done with threads, that’s fairly easy. You can come over to the Julia discourse if you need more help `;)`